# Реализовать генераторы

Tags: python, функции, генераторы

Теряюсь, как должна выглядеть самая первая функция

Реализуйте три функции-генератора (`integers, squares и take`).

1. Функция `integers` - бесконечный поток чисел.
2. Функция `squares` -  выводит квадраты генератора чисел `integers`.
3. Функция `take` возвращает первые `n` значений из переданного генератора.

Пример вывода:

```
>>> print(take(5, squares()))
```

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: в чем у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Каким образом генерируется самая первая функция? (с потоком чисел)
Не совсем понимаю, как она должна выглядеть.

Comment: @math_dummy как генератор псевдослучайных чисел. Стандартный или самописный.

Comment: Очень странное ТЗ. По такому описанию `integers` можно реализовать, как `while True: yield 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если взять квадратный корень значений вашего примера вы увидем

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

то есть функция `integers` должна возвращать числа от единицы до бесконечности

```
def integers():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
```